# ERC20 Tokens and exchanges

Tags: erc-20

Recently a lot of ERC20 tokens have been created and issued. I have seen also the main exchanges handle the larger tokens for exchange but not the smaller ones.

Has anyone details of exchanging ERC20 based tokens?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22748)

Answer (score 4):

There are exchanges for ERC20 tokens. Liqui.io and EtherDelta are two popular ones. Liqui is centralized while EtherDelta is decentralized.